# how to fix "empty button" web accessability error when using bootstrap's glyhicons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, wai-aria, glyphicons

I have a page where a button is labelled with a glyphicon (bootstrap).

I have a new requirement that there must be no "Errors" when the page is checked with the "Wave" tool ( https://wave.webaim.org/extension/ ).

The problem is that Wave throws an Error for the button because it is an "empty button".

I tried to use an image with alt text. That fixes the Wave error, but it makes the button slightly larger, and I am also uneasy about the abuse of the image for this.

This is the minimal version of my page showing the problem:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" alt="UP button">
</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to ensure accessibility (provide alternative text for the glyphicon) than dummy img?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of adding an image with an alt text, add `aria-label` or `title` attribute on the button with the required text.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button aria-label="UP button" title="UP button">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I already have wave installed on my chrome, just checked it doesnt show the error any more.

Answer (score 1):

For good accessibility every interaction element needs to have an text, in your case you could add the corresponding text to the button element in an extra tag, which is invisible but technical readable.

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    border: 0;
}
```

This class is already included in bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/accessibility/

To have an readable text there is also the possibility to add an `aria-label` attribute as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute
But I'm not sure if this fits the checker you mentioned.

Your code extenden with aditional description and aria-label:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button aria-label="description">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Description</span>
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button aria-label="description">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Description</span>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" alt="UP button">
</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint that bootstrap has a built in style for invisible element via the "sr-only" class. However in my particular case, aria-label is enough.

Comment: i just wanted to present different approaches (aria-lable and hidden text) because both would solve the question